# jQuery: Clone event(s) from one element to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to clone event from one element, to another.

For example:

```
$('.somelink').click({data:data},somefunc);
```

I need event in another place in document for element with different class.

Comment: The question should be edited to reflect the answer (which actually answers a different question) - something like, Is it possible to initiate several objects with the same event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass multiple selectors to `$()`, separating them by comma. Like this:

```
$('.somelink, .some-otherlink, #third-id').live('click', {data:data}, somefunc);
```

Now they all share the same click event

Comment: Elements .some-otherlink are not yet created at the moment, when event binding happening.

Comment: I updated the solution to use `live` instead. This way you can bind the event and create the elements later, whenever you wish

Comment: Oh, how could i forget about live. Thanks mate! :) Now i know when live is really helpful. :)

Comment: Keep in mind, with live if you ever have to unbind such events you can't use unbind. You have to use 'die' and use it with the same string selector as you used while binding.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about live. If only I could remember how to make css rules apply to all future matches too...

Answer (score 0):

To copy it, you can do:

```
$('.somelink').click( $('.otherlink').attr('onclick') );
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `.clone()` function has an optional `withDataAndEvents` argument which will copy the node itself, all attached events and any inline data.

See http://api.jquery.com/clone/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @moe's answer.  Use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) to bind events to elements even if they are not in the DOM.  They will be bound as soon as they exist.

```
$('.somelink, .some-otherlink, #third-id').live('click',{data:data},somefunc);
```